# Testing react app with enzyme , change rootDir

Tags: javascript, reactjs, enzyme

I have working on a react project to test my react app. 
My root directory is /home for example
My react app is located in /home/MyApp/appModules/src/
inside all my *.js files implementing class 
My react test app is located in /home/MyApp.tst/testModules/ 
In testModules/ directory, there is the package.json , and /src/ directory , **tests** directory, inside all my *.test.js [test file]

I am trying to change the root directory with configuration of package.json

```
"jest": {
    "rootDir": [
      "./../../"
    ]
  },
```

but I have the error message when I run the command npm run coverage

```
react-scripts test --env=jsdom --coverage


Out of the box, Create React App only supports overriding these Jest options:

  • collectCoverageFrom
  • coverageReporters
  • coverageThreshold
  • globalSetup
  • globalTeardown
  • resetMocks
  • resetModules
  • snapshotSerializers
  • watchPathIgnorePatterns.

These options in your package.json Jest configuration are not currently supported by Create React App:

  • rootDir
```

If you wish to override other Jest options, you need to eject from the default setup. You can do so by running npm run eject but remember that this is a one-way operation. You may also file an issue with Create React App to discuss supporting more options out of the box.

If I eject the project with npm run eject, I can no more run es6 javascript test file ...

Have you any idea to help me ? 
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The name already hints at the answer: user `collectCoverageFrom` to specify your directory `/home/MyApp.tst/testModules/` if you want to keep this folder structure.

Or:

Move your tests and `package.json` within `src` and it should find them automatically